# How to set other fields as required in Craft Commerce checkout process?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, form, validation

I'm using Craft Commerce with the default checkout template. At the step of completing addresses, only First Name, Last Name & Country are required fields by default.

As I'll sell non-digital products, other fields like Address, City, Zip Code must be required and the next step of the checkout process (i.e. Shipping) should not be reached if some fields are still empty.

How can I make these other fields required with Craft validation ?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that this kind of question has already been asked, despite I was asking if there were a more native way than writing a plugin (but it seems not).